# How to setup an include path to be relative from the source location in C++Builder?

Tags: c++builder

I have some libraries with the headers at `..\inc`. The other compilers I use work fine with `..\inc` in the include path, however it's not working with C++Builder.  I tried `..\inc\` as well.

Is there a macro or value that can be used to tell it to search the path based off the source directory?

**Edit:**

The project is in **\libsrc\c++builder**

The source is in **\libsrc\libname\src**

The includes are in **\libsrc\libname\inc**

(There are a lot of libraries but build so they all consolidate to a single .lib now.)

so the reference from source would be **..\inc**

The start my my include path list is:

```
.\
.\inc\
..\..\inc\
```

Comment: It should already be doing that by default. Can you please show what your config actually looks like?

Comment: Probably relative to the folder containing the project file.  What is your project folder structure?

Comment: According to the documentation, a list of build macros is available related to "build events" the same macros may be available in the paths. https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Build_Event_Commands

Comment: added additional details.